# Java WS Authenticator in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, authentication, sun

At the moment I am struggling with a bug in Sun's class `java.net.Authenticator`. It seems that the `Authenticator` class has a system wide static `Authenticator`. This results in the following problem in my multi-threaded application.

1. Thread 1 - Authenticates for User 1
2. Thread 2 - Authenticates for User 2
3. Thread 1 - Executes the code to download messages for User 1

At this point, the system will get the messages for User 2 instead of the messages for User 1.

I have tried searching for a solution. Many suggested trying the following code:

```
AuthCacheValue.setAuthCache(new AuthCacheImpl());
Authenticator.setDefault(exchangeAuthenticator);
```

However, this does not work for me since my application is multi-threaded (`exchangeAuthenticator` will always be set to the authenticator initialized in the latest thread).

If anyone has any idea, even a hack would do at the moment, I would really appreciate that, since at the moment the only 'neat' solution is to place a `synchronized` on the main execution method with a dramatic effect on performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, your best bet is to ditch the builtin http support and get [Apache's HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

If that's not an option, create a single object extending Authenticator, but store the username and password in [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) instances. That way each thread can retrieve it's own values.